# Is it possible to have multiple colors with a Titanium Appcelerator button bar? Titanium.UI.createButtonBar

Tags: javascript, titanium, titanium-mobile

This is my code thus far. I have a button bar with two options. I would like to change the color of the second option. I'm not quite sure how to accomplish this. I was able to set up the click function by checking the index, but unsuccessful in trying to change the colors.

```
var headerEmail = Titanium.UI.createButtonBar({ 
  labels:['cory@gmail.com', 'Logout'], 
  backgroundColor:(labels[0] == 0) ? '#000' : '#fff'

});

headerEmail.addEventListener('click', function(e){
  //alert(e.index);
  if(e.index == 1){
    var LoginWindow = require('/ui/LoginWindow')();      
    LoginWindow.open();
    TabContainer.close(); 
  }

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have tried with    headerEmail.children[1], i mean you can try like this,

```
var headerEmail = Titanium.UI.createButtonBar({ 
  labels:['cory@gmail.com', 'Logout'], 
  backgroundColor:(labels[0] == 0) ? '#000' : '#fff'

});

headerEmail.children[1].setbackgroundColor('#fff');
```